# Correct way of updating user claims on client side

Tags: asp.net, oauth, identity, claims-based-identity, jwt

Currently I'm working on project, where we have implemented oauth over asp.net identity using jwt tokens. So far, everything is good and seems right, but recently we have run to a problem. It's more architectural than technical. I tried to search for best practices, could not find anything valuable, so maybe you can help.

Now the problem: Imagine, you have jwt (or any other) token, that contains some claims that can be used on client side. Next step is that user updates some information, which is represented as claim in token (for example phone number).

Question: what is correct way, to reflect this changes in token? First thing, that comes to mind is refresh token, so as soon as user updates some sensitive data, request refresh token and it will contain updated information. But what if I don't use refresh tokens? Than I have to wait for the moment, when user is logged out and than, after next login, issue new token with updated claims.

Other option is to log out user and force him to log in again, but I don't really thing that this is good idea from user experience perspective

Third thing is to get rid of claims and store this information in local storage or somewhere else and automatically update it on phone number update. But in this case, it means that I have to abandon claims, what I also don't like.

Can someone point to correct solution of this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Going for refresh token will be best practice to do in this scenario because user should not be prompted by this process and all the things will get completed in the background.
For in-depth analysis you can see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIGZxeQUUFU).